# Android View Parameter for OnClickListener Method

Tags: java, android, android-widget, onclicklistener

please dont mind if   stupid question  but please  i need to clear my confusion ..

For  `OnClickListener`  on  a button in android  i did  put this in `main.xml`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="clicked"
/>
```

and in  java file i did

```
  public void clicked(View v)
  {
   //  my code here 
  }
```

my question is  why we need to pass `View view`   when we call   `clicked` method .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK,

Because method is called without getting the Button in onCreate. And in order to access that Button you need to have a view.

i.e
           View v represents your button view.

If you want to access button , suppose you want to get text on It. How do you get it without getting button by using `findViewbyId` ?
       you will get your button like this

```
Button b=(Button)v;
```

To get the text

```
String text=b.getText();
```

So here we are not getting the button by using `findViewById`

In general if you want to access the button you need to get that object. But here you'll get that from the view. Without using `findViewById`.

Comment: ok View is  because  button extends it  ,  why we need  its object view  ?

Comment: @Sikander you can have one method for more that one Button. In this case you should know how to differentiate them from each other. Each widget can have defined its own id and you can differentiate them with this `id` with View's method `v.getId()`

Comment: @Sajmon but in xml i wrote   android:onClick="clicked"  so in   clicked  method i can handle  only this button  , am i right ?

Comment: @Sikander He means to say you can call clicked method for more than one button. i.e If your xml has four buttons then you can set android:onClick="clicked" for all the four buttons, and in order to differentiate them you need to use v.get()==R.id.button1 etc..

Comment: @Sikander yes you can assign same method signature for more than one Button how Pragnani pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

The first reason comes in my mind is that you could attach several views to the same method and using v.getId() you could behave according to the view which was pressed.

Generally speaking, having the view related to the event might be useful for several reasons such as changing some of its attributes.